# inline define for include in jsf

Tags: java, jsf

It's possible to do next by jsf facelets?

I want to extend reusable.xhtml with additional html columns

reusable.xhtml

```
<ui:composition>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <ui:insert name="additional_headers"></ui:insert>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${beanChooser.chosenBean.entitiesToShow}" var="item">
        <tr id="#{beanChooser.chosenBean.shortEntityName.toLowerCase()}${item.id}">
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <ui:insert name="additional_columns"></ui:insert>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</ui:composition>




<html>
<ui:composition template="/masterTemplate.xhtml" ...>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <ui:include src="../reusable.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="additional_columns">
                <td>
                   Additional EL Expression
                </td>
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="additional_headers">
                <th>
                    STATIC 
                </th>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:include>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

if it's not impossible, what is the best practice to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is `<ui:decorate>` instead of `<ui:include>` (check out the `<!-- HERE -->` markers):

```
<ui:composition template="/masterTemplate.xhtml" ...>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <ui:decorate template="../reusable.xhtml"><!-- HERE -->
            <ui:define name="additional_columns">
                <td>
                   Additional EL Expression
                </td>
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="additional_headers">
                <th>
                    STATIC 
                </th>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:decorate>                            <!-- HERE -->
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: it's possible to use ${item.field} inside define, in case when reusable.xhtml contains   <c:forEach items=".." var="item"> ?

Comment: You mean something like `<ui:define name="...">${item.field}</ui:define>`? I.e. the `${item.field}` unwrapped inside it? I do not remeber, but if not, you can always wrap it in a `<h:outputText>`.